# How to run for each loop in XSLT until some condition is fulfilled

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to put all text in div HTML tag that comes after heading2 attribute of W:pPr tag in XML file until next heading2 attribute appears. This is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "doc.xsl"?>

<w:document
    xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing"
    xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing"
    xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
    xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
    xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml"
    xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml"
    xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup"
    xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk"
    xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
    xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00885875" w:rsidRDefault="001E1A54" w:rsidP="001E1A54">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>My First Course</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="001E1A54" w:rsidRDefault="001E1A54" w:rsidP="001E1A54">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>My First Slide</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="001E1A54" w:rsidRDefault="001E1A54" w:rsidP="008B5F33">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="CourseParagraph"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="001E1A54">
                <w:t>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words etc.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="008B5F33" w:rsidRDefault="008B5F33" w:rsidP="008B5F33">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="CourseParagraph"/>
            </w:pPr>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="008B5F33" w:rsidRDefault="008B5F33" w:rsidP="008B5F33">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="Heading2"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r>
                <w:t>My Second Slide</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
        </w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="001E1A54" w:rsidRPr="001E1A54" w:rsidRDefault="001E1A54" w:rsidP="001E1A54">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="CourseParagraph"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="001E1A54">
                <w:t>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>

        <w:p w:rsidR="001E1A54" w:rsidRPr="001E1A54" w:rsidRDefault="001E1A54" w:rsidP="001E1A54">
            <w:pPr>
                <w:pStyle w:val="CourseParagraph"/>
            </w:pPr>
            <w:r w:rsidRPr="001E1A54">
                <w:t>this is copied</w:t>
            </w:r>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="001E1A54" w:rsidRPr="001E1A54">
            <w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
            <w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
            <w:cols w:space="720"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

The HTML format should be something like this

```
<div>
<h2>Text of w:p tag where attribute value of w:pStyle is Heading2<h2>
<p> Text of w:p tag where attribute value of w:pStyle is CourseParagraph/>
<div>
```

The above div will contain all the text until a next heading2 comes and a new div will form when it encounter next heading2.

I am using this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>

                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="//w:body">

        <xsl:for-each select="w:p">
            <xsl:if test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='Heading2']">
                <div>
                    <h2>
                        <xsl:value-of select="w:r/w:t"/>
                    </h2>

                    <xsl:for-each select="following::w:p">

                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='CourseParagraph']">
                                <p>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="w:r/w:t"/>
                                </p>
                            </xsl:when>

                        </xsl:choose>

                    </xsl:for-each>

                </div>

            </xsl:if>


        </xsl:for-each>


    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the output, all the paragraph values after a heading2 are appearing. I was not able to restrict until a next heading2 attribiute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for-each-group` instead e.g.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="w:p" group-starting-with="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='Heading2']]">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
  </div>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

then write templates

```
<xsl:template match="w:p">
  <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle[@w:val='Heading2']]">
  <h2>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="w:r/w:t"/>
  </h2>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: ThankYou for the answer, but it is giving "parsing failed" error after using for each group.

Comment: You have tagged the question as [tag:xslt-2.0] so I would assume you use an XSLT 2 processor. Parse errors usually mean the XML or the XSLT is not well-formed, can't tell from a comment where that goes wrong, I have used your input and my suggestions at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBth successfully without getting a parse error. Consider to ask a new question with details about that error if you can't resolve it yourself. Unless of course you don't use an XSLT 2 processor, then you need to retag your question and I will delete my answer.

Comment: I am using mozila for the output is its due to the browser?
I am using version 2 only.

Comment: Browsers like Mozilla, Chrome, Edge, IE only support XSLT 1.0 so no idea why you tagged the question as [tag:xslt-2.0] if you want to run XSLT in the browser. `xsl:for-each-group` does not exist in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Got it. Thanks 
Is there anyway to solve it using xslt 1.0